How do I secure a website for seamless authenticated access from an App?
I'm working on the application environment below. It involves a mobile App which uses an AWS lambda based API. The App requires authentication and the API is secured using JWTs.

I need to introduce a view of an externally hosted authenticated web application into the App with the following requirements:

The App user should have a seamless 'logged in' experience, they should not have to login to the external application.
The external application is provided to the App using HTML over HTTPS. The App displays this using a webview component (specifically, a WKWebView in iOS).
In the future the App will display the external application natively, using the external application's API
The external application should not be available to a browser client - it must be secured so that it is only accessible from the webview in the App.
The external application will not be part of the same domain as the App's API, nor will have any shared authentication method.

We're currently considering the following setup:

The App will make a request (connection 1) to the API, requesting the external application credentials/session details for the user.

The API Lambda sends the user's details to the external application (connection 3)
The external application establishes a session for the user (this may involve creating the user locally) and returns the user's session/access credentials.
The user's session/access credentials are passed back to the App via the API Lambda.
The App receives the details it needs to access the external application back from the API request.


The App sets up the webview using the URL of the external application and the required headers/cookies from the received details.

The App sets up the 'logged in session' by setting the request headers/cookies in the webview component
The external application receives a request for a logged in session (connection 2)
The App user sees the authenticated external application, without any visibility of any session setup/login step



With regard to ensuring access to the external web application is prevented if it is not from the App we are able to establish filters/rules and have considered the following:

Setup a known referrer/user agent and ensure the request matches
Add a custom HTTP header with a value which can be verified as having come from the App. Perhaps we'd sign this with a shared secret as part of the flow above.
It has been suggested that we might use request certificates - we have no experience of this and would need to investigate this to work out if that is the case

I'm looking for advice/suggestions to help us make the best choices. Is there something we could consider which I didn't mention above?
Thanks for any help.
